# What can I do to speed this slow query up?

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, sybase

We have a massive, multi-table Sybase query we call the `get_safari_exploration_data` query, that fetches all sorts of info related to explorers going on a safari, and all the animals they encounter.

This query is slow, and I've been asked to speed it up. The first thing that jumps out at me is that there doesn't seem to be a pressing need for the nested `SELECT` statement inside the outer `FROM` clause. In that nested `SELECT`, there also seems to be several fields that aren't necessary (`vegetable`, `broomhilda`, `devoured`, etc.). I'm also skeptical about the use of the joins ("`*=`" instead of "INNER JOIN...ON").

```
SELECT
    dog_id,
    cat_metadata,
    rhino_id,
    buffalo_id,
    animal_metadata,
    has_4_Legs,
    is_mammal,
    is_carnivore,
    num_teeth,
    does_hibernate,
    last_spotted_by,
    last_spotted_date,
    purchased_by,
    purchased_date,
    allegator_id,
    cow_id,
    cow_name,
    cow_alias,
    can_be_ridden
FROM
(
    SELECT
        mp.dog_id as dog_id,
        ts.cat_metadata + '-yoyo' as cat_metadata,
        mp.rhino_id as rhino_id,
        mp.buffalo_id as buffalo_id,
        mp.animal_metadata as animal_metadata,
        isnull(mp.has_4_Legs, 0) as has_4_Legs,
        isnull(mp.is_mammal, 0) as is_mammal,
        isnull(mp.is_carnivore, 0) as is_carnivore,
        isnull(mp.num_teeth, 0) as num_teeth,
        isnull(mp.does_hibernate, 0) as does_hibernate,
        jungle_info.explorer as last_spotted_by,
        exploring_journal.spotted_datetime as last_spotted_date,
        jungle_info.explorer as purchased_by,
        early_exploreration_journal.spotted_datetime as purchased_date,
        alleg_id as allegator_id,
        ho.cow_id,
        ho.cow_name,
        ho.cow_alias,
        isnull(mp.is_ridable,0) as can_be_ridden,
        ts.cat_metadata as broomhilda,
        ts.squirrel as vegetable,
        convert (varchar(15), mp.rhino_id) as tms_id,
        0 as devoured
    FROM
        mammal_pickles mp,
        very_tricky_animals vt,
        possibly_venomous pv,
        possibly_carniv_and_tall pct,
        tall_and_skinny ts,
        tall_and_skinny_type ptt,
        exploration_history last_exploration_history,
        master_exploration_journal exploring_journal,
        adventurer jungle_info,
        exploration_history first_exploration_history,
        master_exploration_journal early_exploreration_journal,
        adventurer jungle_info,
        hunting_orders ho
    WHERE
        mp.exploring_strategy_id = 47
        and mp.cow_id = ho.cow_id
        and ho.cow_id IN (20, 30, 50)
        and mp.rhino_id = vt.rhino_id
        and vt.version_id = pv.version_id
        and pv.possibly_carniv_and_tall_id = pct.possibly_carniv_and_tall_id
        and vt.tall_and_skinny_id = ts.tall_and_skinny_id
        and ts.tall_and_skinny_type_id = ptt.tall_and_skinny_type_id
        and mp.alleg_id *= last_exploration_history.exploration_history_id
        and last_exploration_history.master_exploration_journal_id *= exploring_journal.master_exploration_journal_id
        and exploring_journal.person_id *= jungle_info.person_id
        and mp.first_exploration_history_id *= first_exploration_history.exploration_history_id
        and first_exploration_history.master_exploration_journal_id *= early_exploreration_journal.master_exploration_journal_id
        and early_exploreration_journal.person_id *= jungle_info.person_id
) TEMP_TBL
```

So I ask:

- Am I correct about the nested `SELECT`?
- Am I correct about the unnecessary fields inside the nested `SELECT`?
- Am I correct about the structure/syntax/usage of the joins?
- Is there anything else about the structure/nature of this query that jumps out at you as being terribly inefficient/slow?

Unfortunately, unless there is irrefutable, matter-of-fact proof that decomposing this large query into smaller queries is beneficial in the long run, management will simply not approve refactoring it out into multiple, smaller queries, as this will take considerable time to refactor and test. Thanks in advance for any help/insight here!

Comment: The nested SELECT may or may not provide a performance hit. It depends on the execution plan (I can't tell you since that's a lot of tables to model). If it's using a temporary table, then definitely remove the nested SELECT (you can find out using the EXPLAIN plan). 

Otherwise, the extra fields won't hurt anything UNLESS they require an unnecessary join. Again it depends on whether the execution plan uses a temporary table (the optimizer will remove unnecessary tables from the query IF the sub-query isn't copied to a temporary table first).

Comment: Thanks @jtv4k (+1) - to clarify, you're saying that *if* the execution plan (which I can see via `EXPLAIN`) shows Sybase as using the `TEMP_TBL`, then I definitely need to remove the nested `SELECT`? If that's what you're saying, can you explain why the nested `SELECT` and associated `TEMP_TBL` are "bad" (slow) for the execution plan?

Comment: Ahhh, I am starting to "get it". If I understand correctly: if the subquery is copied to a temp table then the optimizer won't remove unnessary joins; otherwise the unnecessary joins will remain as part of the execution plan, and they will adversely affect performance? **Is that a fair assessment?** Thanks again!

Comment: Correct -- the query optimizer _should_ look at the subquery, realize it can be merged with the top query and remove unnecessary fields. Optimizers sometimes get confused and think sub-queries require temporary tables (SLOW SLOW SLOW!). If it copies the results to a temp table, it'll do so BEFORE considering the outside query, thus not eliminating unnecessary joins.

Comment: is this a joke? if yes, it's hilarious!

Comment: This has "management"?!?

Comment: Are all of these tables highly dynamic or could some of the joins be done occasionally and cashed to another table instead of being run every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Am I correct about the nested SELECT?

You would be in some cases, but a competent planner would collapse it and ignore it here.

- Am I correct about the unnecessary fields inside the nested SELECT?

Yes, especially considering that some of them don't show up at all in the final list of fields.

- Am I correct about the structure/syntax/usage of the joins?

Insofar as I'm aware, `*=` and `=*` are merely syntactic sugar for a left and right join, but I might be wrong in stating that. If not, then they merely force the way joins occur, but they may be necessary for your query to work at all.

- Is there anything else about the structure/nature of this query that jumps out at you as being terribly inefficient/slow?

Yes.

Firstly, you've some calculations that aren't needed, e.g. `convert (varchar(15), mp.rhino_id) as tms_id`. Perhaps a join or two as well, but I admittedly haven't looked at the gory details of the query.

Next, you might have a problem with the db design itself, e.g. a cow_id field. (Seriously? :-) )

Last, there occasionally is something to be said about doing multiple queries instead of a single one, to avoid doing tons of joins.

In a blog, for instance, it's usually a good idea to grab the top 10 posts, and then to use a separate query to fetch their tags (where id in (id1, id2, etc.)). In your case, the selective part seems to be around here:

```
    mp.exploring_strategy_id = 47
    and mp.cow_id = ho.cow_id
    and ho.cow_id IN (20, 30, 50)
```

so maybe isolate that part in one query, and then build an `in ()` clause using the resulting IDs, and fetch the cosmetic bits and pieces in one or more separate queries.

Oh, and as point out by Gordon, check your indexes as well. But then, note that the indexes may end up of little use without splitting the query into more manageable parts.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following approach.

First, rewrite the query using ANSI standard joins with the `on` clause.  This will make the conditions and filtering much easier to understand.  Also, this is "safe" -- you should get exactly the same results as the current version.  Be careful, because the `*=` is an outer join, so not everything is an inner join.

I doubt this step will improve performance.

Then, check each of the reference tables and be sure that the join keys have indexes on them *in the reference table*.  If keys are missing, then add them in.

Then, check whether the left outer joins are necessary.  There are filters on tables that are left outer join'ed in . . . these filters convert the outer joins to inner joins.  Probably not a performance hit, but you never know.

Then, consider indexing the fields used for filtering (in the `where` clause).

And, learn how to use explain capabilities.  Any nested loop joins (without an index) as likely culprits for performance problems.

As for the nested select, I think Sybase is smart enough to "do the right thing".  Even if it wrote out and re-read the result set, that probably would have a marginal effect on the query compared to getting the joins right.

If this is your real data structure, by the way, it sounds like a very interesting domain.  It is not often that I see a field called `allegator_id` in a table.

Comment: These are all good suggestions, but aren't you treating the symptoms rather than the cause?  Assuming this is a real question, there are some massive, massive issues with the database design that should first be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer some of your questions.

You think that the fields (vegetable, broomhilda, devoured) in nested SELECT could be causing performance issue. Not necessarily. The two unused fields (vegetable, broomhilda) in nested SELECT are from the ts table but the cat_metadata field which is being used is also from ts table. So unless cat_metadata is being covered by index used on ts table, there wont be any performance impact. Because, to extract cat_metadata field the data page from table will need to be fetched anyway. The extraction of other two fields will take little CPU, that's it. So don't worry about that. The 'devoured' field is also a constant. That will not affect the performance either.

Dennis pointed out about usage of convert function convert(varchar(15), mp.rhino_id). I disagree that that will effect performance as it will consume CPU only.

Lastly I would say, try using the set table count to 13, as there are 13 tables in there. Sybase uses four tables at a time for optimisation.